# Run android studio offline

Tags: android, offline

I downloaded a .zip file in github and import it in android studio. Now i can view the source code and XML but I've got a problem, It doesn't work when I'm offline. What  causes it and how to solve my problem?

I searched about it and it's all about maven, which I don't know what is.

Comment: I am not sure about maven, however whenever i download a project from online, i usually choose the option of import project(eclipse, adt, gradle). [check out this link for image](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*SIICx3rhL5oI__3FDc6xRw.png) This usually sorts out the dependency problems.

Comment: Yes,I chose this option too" import project(eclipse, adt, gradle)". but there is something in  
  repositiories {
   jcenter() 
maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
maven{url'https:// haibison.bitbucket.io/maven-repos'}
maven{url "https://github.com/omadahealth-nexus/raw/master/release"}
 }